# MySQL MSI appears to be installing wrong (latest) MySQL version

Tags: mysql-5.6, installation, version-control, mysql-8.0

For compatibility reasons with other software, I'm trying to install MySQL 5.6.40 on Windows 10. Any version from 5.7 onward is incompatible with my other programs.

I've been trying to use the MSI installer but - no matter what version of 5.6 I try to install - the only server option I get is 8.0.

The installer has the correction version in its name (e.g. (mysql-installer-web-community-5.6.41.0.msi) but when I run it, I only get version 8.0.11 appearing for installation. I've gone into the Add screen, and there's no other versions showing under server. There doesn't seem to be the ability to point to a different version during installation.

I get the same problem if I try the [normal download site](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.6.html) or the [archive site](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/installer/).

I would prefer to use the MSI installer rather than downloading the zip files, as I am not confident with installing a database from a zip.

I've been searching to see if this has been reported by others, and I haven't found any comments on this.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you fully removed previous MySQL version (including all components, folders and registry keys) before install? Do it. And temporary disable network connection to Inet during install...

Comment: Yes, it was the internet connection during installation that was causing the most recent server version to install. Pulling out the network cable solved the problem. Do you want to put your comment into an answer so I can tick and upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you fully removed previous MySQL version (including all components, folders and registry keys) before install? Do it.

And temporary disable network connection to Inet during install... it prevents offering to install up-to-date version.